# Is it possible to move the Tridion questions from other Stack Exchange sites to here?

Tags: discussion

We have over 1000 Tridion specific questions on other Stack Exchange sites. Is it possible to move them to this site to prevent duplicate questions?

Comment: Would the plan not to be to select the cream of the crop and manually transfer them over to the new site with concise questions and answers to set a standard for the rest of the questions?

Comment: Yes, I wondered about this too. Seems a shame to have all of that valuable information in a different place

Comment: We could only do this after the site goes public. Also, can we prevent new questions from being asked on SO or ServerFault?

Comment: It's a shame you can't have questions in Stackoverflow tagged with #tridion automatically show up on the Tridion StackExchange site. I can see the Android tag is very populair in StackOverflow even though there is a dedicated site for it...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While it's technically possible to migrate questions, the migration paths are not set up until a site becomes well-established. But beyond that technical limitation, building this community from the old, pre-answered questions of *another* site would do **this** site a terrible disservice. **That's not how you want to build this site.**

Forget for a moment that other sites may not *want* their content removed like that (along with the the knowledge and reputation earned). Consider that, from day one, your brand new site will be **filled with old, pre-answered anonymous questions,** as the original authors are off on another site. Your tags will be inherited from another site, regardless of how this community wants to organize content here. Comments would be largely meaningless and scattered with links to another site. Voting wont reflect the activity on *this* community, which makes it difficult to build an avid higher-reputation community to watch over this site — [Vote Early, Vote Often](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/).

The idea of creating a site dedicated to Tridion is to build a community was supposedly not being well-served by *another* site. I wouldn't rush to simply migrate a lot of old content. Focus on building your *own* community. Give yourselves some time to figure out the scope and culture of **this** site. You should focus on building your *own* content with properly curated content, built with the community and expertise that genuinely belongs here.

That was the point of creating this site in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for this insight Robert, it indeed seems to make sense to focus more on the new than on the old right now.

Comment: Thanks Robert - I was worried about duplication of all the questions that are already out there, but you've provided a very compelling argument against moving questions here! We'll definitely keep the focus on the new site.

Comment: Now that our own site is already well-established, I think it might be time to revisit this issue. It's worth noting that the questioners and answerers on other sites like SO are in general the same people that you'll find here. We used to use SO, SF etc., until we had our own site, and then we moved here.

Comment: @Dominic unless those questions are deemed off topic elsewhere, we have no cause to remove them from another site, along with the reputation those users earned there. See https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/

Answer (score 5):

[How to migrate question to programmers.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91381/how-to-migrate-question-to-programmers-stackexchange-com) indicates it is possible to migrate questions, but this site needs to be public first so it looks.

Which means we will have to go over the existing questions when this site goes live (if we feel that is appropriate). At that point we could also migrate the new questions being asked there (which means vote to close them as off topic). At the time being there isn't much we can do with preventing new questions from being asked in other SE sites.